NGINX ProxyPass with Regular Expression and Resolver doesn't work
I'm setting up a NGINX server and I created a block with regular expression and added a ProxyPass directive using the captured parts with the regex.
I'm using the URL http://localhost:8089/first-context/custom-path/test to test. Im exposing the port 80 of NGINX as 8089. My .conf file is as following:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /first-context/test {
        try_files /main.html =404;
    }
    
    location ~ /(first-context|second-context)/custom-path/(.*)$ {
        # resolver 127.0.0.1; #8.8.8.8
        set $context $1;
        set $path $2;
        set $custom_upstream localhost;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80/${context}/${path};
    }
}

Without a resolver, I get a different error:

2024/12/19 05:09:00 [error] 29#29: *1 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /first-context/custom-path/test HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8089"

With a resolver directive it fails with errors like this:

2024/12/19 05:07:18 [error] 29#29: send() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53

I expected NGINX to return the main.html when the URL http://localhost:8089/first-context/custom-path/test is opened. But i'm getting 502 Bad Gateway with the errors described above in the console.
Could anyone explain why the resolver is not working and how to fix it?

AFAIR no common-used external resolver is able to resolve the localhostdomain to 127.0.0.1 IP address; however the simplest way to resolve your issue should be changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in your nginx configuration.

So the way NGINX resolves the upstream address in your proxy_pass is via DNS. If you say your server_name is localhost, NGINX will try to resolve it via a DNS, and it will ultimately fail without a resolver specified.
Therefore, you need to set a resolver to one of the common DNS server. I usually use the Google servers (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4). This of course assumes that you do not have a DNS server running on your machine at 127.0.0.1.
Then, there is the issue that NGINX can not recognize variables in the URI. In simple terms, it treats your proxy_pass to http://localhost:80/${context}/${path} as an invalid URI, and it fails. This is not a fault of NGINX, but rather just a misunderstanding of how NGINX handles these scenarios. You can set the proxy header to change the URI to X-Original-URI + the two variables you are passing.
Here is a solution:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /first-context/test {
        try_files /main.html =404;
    }

    location ~ /(first-context|second-context)/custom-path/(.*)$ {
        set $context $1;
        set $path $2;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI /$context/$path;
    }
}

I hope this helps.
